# Best way to log an error

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, error, debug-logs

Which is the best way to log an error/debug logs in Production enviornment (Salesforce/apex)?

Comment: @Raul i edited the question. In the production environment which is the best way to do that if developer does not have access to the production environment and Bussiness analysts are looking after the org. Which solution will be the best to make the BA's understand what is going on in the code. Should we create custom object or is there any other solution available?

Comment: You can create Error logging object storing Stacktrace and class or other attributes. You can control the log entry through custom hierarchy having a checkbox to check for profiles/users.